# find if specific column is having the specific string and delete the column if that string is present.

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I want to delete the File if it's 3rd column contains the String "BMR", string might be - "BMR13234" , means 'BMR' is the static part of that string it can have any other chars.

So if the 3rd column contains - "BMR*" ( * refers to any chars ) then that whole 3rd column should get deleted from the file.

For example : 
Input:

```
"ABC","0.20","BMR1234442","2001-01-01"
"LMN","0.00","BMR2490289","2008-01-01"
"LTD","0.20","BMR2345577","2001-01-01"
```

The output should be: ( only if BMR is present else the 3rd column should not get deleted)

```
"ABC","0.20","2001-01-01"
"LMN","0.00","2008-01-01"
"LTD","0.20","2001-01-01"
```

Please suggest.

Comment: So if `BMR` is in *any* 3rd column of a row, it has to be removed from the whole file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One `awk` solution

```
awk -F, '$3~/^BMR/ {$3=x} {sub(/,,/,",")}1' OFS=, file
"ABC","0.20","2001-01-01"
"LMN","0.00","2008-01-01"
"LTD","0.20","2001-01-01"
```

Test if field `3` starting with `BMR`, if yes set it to blank.
Sub removes the extra empty field, if that is what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/^\(\("[^"]*",\)\{2\}\)"BMR[^"]*",/\1/' YourFile
```

Just insure that structure `"blaba","blabla","BMR` does not include space between `","`